# Passing a database value from a jsp to a controller in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a user page where I am viewing a specific users details. I want to be able to add this user as a "friend". I sort of understand the technical details I will need to do to add this user as a friend, I am just unsure how to pass the jsp value to the controller.

This is what my friend entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friend")
public class Friend {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name = "friend_username")
private String friend_username;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "friend_username", referencedColumnName="username", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private User user;

public Friend() {
    this.user = new User();
}

public Friend(int id, String friend_username, User user) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.friend_username = friend_username;
    this.user = user;
}
```

In my JSP file I am viewing a user's details like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Username:</b></td>
    <td>${user.username}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Email:</b></td>
    <td>${user.email}
<tr>
    <td><b>Name:</b></td>
    <td>${user.name}
```

How could I pass the user.username value to the controller? I know i'll be able to get the current username by using Principal. If anyone could help or has any examples I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Once the value is within a JSP (and therefore already displayed, the response has already been closed) you need to have the user trigger an interaction again. Meaning the user has to trigger a new request alerting another controller that he wants to add a friend.

Either that, or you could read up on Spring Webflow.

Comment: This is a very broad question and a detailed response would involve too many parts. To start you will essentially submit a request of some description passing an identifier as a parameter which will uniquely identify a user. On the server side you can look at using a Spring converter which will take this parameter and retrieve the corresponding friend instance from the database.http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert